# Rabbitmq configuration for multiple customers

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to create a script which would create predefined queues for multiple customers.
Configuration of rabbitMQ is quite a problem for our customers when they want to connect to our service, hence I thought if it's possible to create a script which would create predefined queues and everyone would have the same settings with different routing keys etc.The best would be in python.
I was searching and nothing useful popped out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rabbit MQ portal in the overview tab, you have a facility to export and import definitions. Export definitions will give you the JSON files having all the Queues with the routing key in the selected virtual host. You can update this JSON as per the requirement and upload it again with a different(new virtual host). After successfully uploading, you can see new Queues in the virtual host.